# HashMap inside of a list Kotlin (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to represent a HashMap inside of a List in Kotlin.
The list is structured as:

```
daysOfWeekHashMapOptions = listOf(
    hashMapOf("key" to 0, "label" to "Monday"),
    hashMapOf("key" to 1, "label" to "Tuesday"),
    hashMapOf("key" to 2, "label" to "Wednesday"),
    hashMapOf("key" to 3, "label" to "Thursday"),
    hashMapOf("key" to 4, "label" to "Friday"),
    hashMapOf("key" to 5, "label" to "Saturday"),
    hashMapOf("key" to 6, "label" to "Sunday")
)
```

The way it is set up this way is so that my Firebase Firestore stores the selected days of the week in a list like:

```
daysOfWeek [
    0: {
        key: 0
        label: "Monday"
    },
    1: ...
]
```

The issue I am having is that I want to make an AutoCompleteText in my Android app so that I can select these values and display them appropriately. Therefore, I want the AutoCompleteText's ArrayAdapter to get each `label` parameter as an option to be selected from. The stored values from the AutoCompleteText's selected options (HashMap) will then be stored in a List/Array. However, being able to 'filter' and split up the list of options and HashMap's is difficult.

In JavaScript this would be something along the lines of `daysOfWeekHashMapOptions.filter(value => value.label)` (maybe). Any help or pointers of the equivalent in Kotlin is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```kotlin
labels = daysOfWeekHashMapOptions.map{ it.get("label") }
```

The value type of `labels` is `List<String>`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! As an extra question. Now if I have a ChipGroup (with Chips) that store the days selected from the AutoCompleteText. How would I find the HashMap value from the `daysOfWeekHashMapOptions` that matches the text (label) value of each Chip? Thanks again :)

Comment: You want to get  'key', according to the 'label'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tugqay Either that, or get the actual value from the `daysOfWeekHashMapOptions`. For instance, I iterate through the list of children within the ChipGroup. Then I want to find all the elements in the `daysOfWeekHashMapOptions` which have a `label` the same the Chip's text

Comment: What do you mean by actual value? And what is the data type of ChipGroup?

Comment: Hi @Tuqay. Sorry for the wording. I've worked it out as: `daysOfWeekHashMapOptions.filter {it["label"] == chip.text.toString()}`. This returns a list containing the days of week hash map values matching the Chip's text.

Comment: Okay. It's good for you to work it out. By the way, why do you keep hashmaps in list instead of creating one hashmap to store keys and labels?

Comment: Good point. I think this is just the way I have structured it, so it looks the way I expect it to in Firestore and for my WebApp that reads the same data. Is there perhaps a better way you would suggest/expect. I don't particularly like the way I've done it either

Comment: I will write that in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your second question:

```kotlin
val map = HashMap<Int,String>()
map.put(0,"Monday")
map.put(1,"Tuesday")
map.put(2,"Wednesday")
map.put(3,"Thursday")
map.put(4,"Friday")
map.put(5,"Saturday")
map.put(6,"Sunday")
```

Your database would look like this:

```
daysOfWeek [
    0: "Monday"
    1: "Tuesday"
    ...........
    6: "Sunday"
]
```

If you are not planning to store anything other than just days of the week, then it is the best way.

Comment: Thanks @Tuqay, I will have a look into doing it this way instead. It definitely makes more sense!